# Looking for a good and complete Enzimology exercises book

Tags: enzymes, exercise

I mean, I want to practice with challenging exercises and I want to know the theory behind them. So, I started reading:

- Organic Chemistry: Yurkanis, P.
- Enzyme kinetics: Bisswanger, H.
- Biotechnology procedures and experiments Handbook: Harisha, S.
  But just the first one has problems and not about enzymes at all.

So, I looking for a good (theoretic) and complete (challenging with exercises) book about enzymes.

Comment: I generally regard book recommendations off-topic. I cannot recommend a book but suggest you see if you can "look inside" [Cornish-Bowden's Fundamentals of Enzyme Kinetics](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780408106177/fundamentals-of-enzyme-kinetics). He is well regarded, and there are some calculations in his book judging by the three pages of solutions to problems. Only three pages though.

Comment: So, why are off-topic?? The book you recommend me is very fine. It cover many of the topics in my syllabus. Just $55. Thanks man.

Comment: The reason it could be considered off-topic as an answer is that any recommendation is subjective opinion, and this is a question and answer site about biological problems. But glad my comment is of use.